# Summernote in typescript and vue

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, summernote

I want to use summernote in Vue component written in Typescript. But I get error:

> Error TS2339  (TS) Property 'summernote' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

My code looks like bellow:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import * as $ from "jquery";
require('summernote');
```

Then in template I have div:

```html
<div ref="mysummernote" id="summernote"><p>Hello Summernote</p></div>
```

and in mounted() I have:

```
$('#summernote').summernote();
```

and this .summernote() method is marked as error with message like on the top. All code is written in typescript. To npm I added summernote package like on this website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/summernote

Comment: I had a lot of issues getting summernote to work with that configuration. In the end I gave up and used this one instead. https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I married **Vue** + **TypeScrypt** + **Summernote**:

Template:

```
<html-editor height="200" :model.sync="yourFieldName"></html-editor>
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/select2": "^4.0.48",
    "@types/summernote": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

And here is my component:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/summernote/index.d.ts" />

Vue.component("html-editor", {
    props : {
        model: {
            required: true
        },
        height: {
            type: String,
            default: "150"
        }
    },
    template: "#html-editor",
    mounted() {           

        let config : Summernote.Options = {
            height: this.height,
            followingToolbar: false, // that needs some tweak see below
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic']]
            ],
            callbacks: {},   
        };            

        let vm = this;
        config.callbacks = {
            onInit: function () {
                $(vm.$el).summernote("code", vm.model);
            },
            onChange: function () {
                vm.$emit("update:model", $(vm.$el).summernote("code"));
            },
        };
        $(this.$el).summernote(config);
    }
})
```

I had to modify `@types/summernote/index.d.ts`:

```
namespace Summernote {
    interface Options {
        ...
        followingToolbar?: boolean;
    }
}
```

(Pull request on the way)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to add the summernote editor to an Angular2 site.

What I did was to add the summernote property to the jQuery typings file.

My project already had a typings file for jQuery - in this case jquery.d.ts (found in the typings folder).

I found the "interface JQuery {" section in that file and added the following line to it:

```
summernote: any;
```

Comment: You haven't had to add it into jQuery typings. Summernote has its own @types-package, so you could just: `npm install -D @types/summernote` - and it would work properly.